# Freemarker: Performing transformations on ElementModel

Tags: xml, xslt, freemarker

I have an instance of a Freemarker ElementModel.  I want to do an XSLT-type transformation on it.  Is there a way of doing this?  Could I, for example, convert the ElementModel to some sort of actual XML node, do the transformation, and then convert this node back into an ElementModel?  Or simply recurse down the ElementModel and change things on the way down?

I'm doing this in Java, if that matters, and will be doing the transformation in a TemplateMethodModelEx.exec method.

Answer (score 0):

With `ElementModel.getNode()` you can get the `org.w3c.dom.Node`, and after that it's the usual (FreeMarker-independent) business. When the new DOM is ready, you can get the current `ObjectWrapper` from the `freemarker.core.Environment` and return `objectWrapper.wrap(newNode)` to the template (and here I assume you are using the default object wrapper, which knows about `Node`-s).